# linq with nullable datetime

Tags: c#, linq

I'm running a linq-to-sql query on a table that contains a nullable datetime like this:

```
 var Output = from s in ....
              select new MyModel() 
              {
                  TheCloseDate = s.TheCloseDate.DateTime.Value
              }
```

However, the variable `TheCloseDate` never gets filled. The MyModel definition of the variable is :

```
public Nullable<DateTime> TheCloseDate { get; set; }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: can you detail `TheCloseDate` / `TheCloseDate.DateTime` ?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: What information do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var Output = from s in ....
              select new MyModel() 
              {
                  TheCloseDate = s.TheCloseDate ?? null // Or whatever you want, like DateTime.Now
              }
```